# In cli how do i convert every line of file into array

Tags: command-line-interface

I want to know how in windows or linux cli convert file with lines in it to array. So new text file is like this `{"line 1", "line 2", "line 3"}`

I tried to use cat with filters but then i got lost, I am not very familiar with cli in general. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a bash script that reads the file line by line and prints each line enclosed by double quotes and preceded by a comma. The first line will be the only line that's not preceded by a comma.

```
echo -n "{"
COMMA=""
while read p; do
    if [ -n "$p" ]; then
      echo -n "$COMMA\"$p\""
      COMMA=","
    fi
done <mylines.txt
echo -n "}"
```

Comment: actually after every line its adding extra empty string like this : `{"line1","","line2",""...`

Comment: @MuhammadUmer does your file have empty lines?